# Formik radio box not selectable

Tags: reactjs, forms, formik

I have a working React component with Formik with initialValues and everything else works perfectly except for the radio box below.

The radio box is not selectable, what could be the bug?

```
<Field
                            name="accountPurpose"
                            render={({ field }) => (
                              <>
                                <div className="radio-item">
                                  <input
                                    {...field}
                                    id="all"
                                    value="all"
                                    checked={field.value === "all"}
                                    name="type"
                                    type="radio"
                                  />
                                  <label htmlFor="all"> All</label>
                                </div>

                                <div className="radio-item">
                                  <input
                                    {...field}
                                    id="distribution"
                                    value="distribution"
                                    name="type"
                                    checked={field.value === "distribution"}
                                    type="radio"
                                  />
                                  <label htmlFor="distribution">
                                    Distribution
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                                <div className="radio-item">
                                  <input
                                    {...field}
                                    id="redemption"
                                    value="redemption"
                                    name="type"
                                    checked={field.value === "redemption"}
                                    type="radio"
                                  />
                                  <label htmlFor="redemption">
                                    {" "}
                                    Redemption
                                  </label>
                                </div>
                              </>
                            )}
                          />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `checked={field.value ===...}` from all inputs and use  `defaultChecked` for just one.

like below

```
        <input
          id="all"
          value="all"
          name="type"
          type="radio"
          defaultChecked
          {...field}
          />
```

Comment: Hi Alex, do I put `defaultChecked={field.value === ...}` for one of the option?

Comment: Just `defaultChecked`,`<input  type="radio" ......... defaultChecked  />`